# How to Render OpenGL on Android with C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, opengl-es, .net-6.0

I have an existing application written in C# for .NET 6 that renders OpenGL with the lightweight OpenTK (v4) OpenGL bindings, which support .NET 5+, Open GL 3+, and OpenGL ES 2+.

According to the [OpenTK FAQ](https://opentk.net/faq.html):

> OpenTK runs on Windows, Linux, and MacOS X.
>
> (Older versions of OpenTK supported Android and iOS as well; current OpenTK might work on these, but it’s untested.)

I am excited by .NET 6's promise of [one unified platform](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/), but I have only seen cross-platform mobile projects that use Microsoft's new [.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui) framework. MAUI appears to be a web view shell that contains a Blazor Web App. I found the code for this shell in the [src/Core/AndroidNative folder of the repository](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main/src/Core/AndroidNative), but it seems very bloated for my purposes. I want to be able to access Android-specific functions without the bloat of Blazor and a web view. According to [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/the-new-net-multi-platform-app-ui-maui/#net-6-and-mobile-sdks), Xamarin.Android might be the answer, but I am not sure how to introduce it into my existing project.

All I need is a simple shell that:

1. [Creates an Activity with a GLSurfaceView](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main/src/Core/AndroidNative)
2. Obtains an OpenGL ES 2 context
3. Runs my current C# code with that context

I would prefer the shell to be in C#, since introducing Java code would complicate my build process and fragment my code base.

- How can I introduce the needed Android-specific code?
- How will this change my build process?
- I know that I need to write OpenGL ES-compatible shaders and that I probably need to change how I save files. What other changes will I need to make to my current code to ensure Android compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bet on .NET Maui because it seems like they don't want to support OpenGL in the future.

As you mentioned you can use Xamarin for this. I recently wrote an article on how to setup OpenGL with Xamarin especially for Android: https://ben-5.azurewebsites.net/2023/10/11/lets-create-a-mobile-game-with-xamarin-and-opengl-part1.
It  explains how to separate platform specific code from you OpenGL code and also how to use shaders.